# Python find index of nan in nan-list yields error only sometimes?

Tags: python, list, numpy, nan

For an all-nan list `a = [np.nan, np.nan]`, `a.index(np.nan)` returns `0`, while for the `np.nan` returned by `b = np.nanmax(a)`, `a.index(b)` gives a `ValueError`. The object ids of `np.nan` and `b` are different. However, if `a` were `[2,3.1]` and `c = np.array(a).tolist()`, then `id(a[1])` and `id(c[1])` would be different as well, nonetheless there is no `ValueError` for `a.index(c[1])`?

How does `list.index()` work under the hood? Does it compare for value equality (I guess not, otherwise `a.index(np.nan)` should return an error because `np.nan != np.nan`)? For object id (again I guess not, otherwise `a.index(c[1])` should return an error)? Why does the example with `a.index(np.nanmax(a))` not work if `a = [np.nan,np.nan]`, while `a.index(np.nan)` does?

```
import numpy as np

a = [np.nan, np.nan]
b = np.nanmax(a)

print(id(np.nan), id(a[0]), id(a[1]), id(b))

a.index(np.nan)
a.index(b)

# Output:
# 47021195940144 47021195940144 47021195940144 47021566155984
#   ...
#   File "<ipython-input-2-fb7cc8fa88c0>", line 9, in <module>
#     a.index(b)
# ValueError: nan is not in list
```

Comment: If you look at `type(np.nan) == type(b)` then you get `False`: `type(np.nan)` is `<class 'float'>` whereas `type(b)` is `<class 'numpy.float64'>`. Why does this happen: `np.nanmax` does convert array-like `a`'s via `a = np.asanyarray(a)` into a `ndarray`, and this conversion produces a `ndarry` of `dtype` `np.float64` which is conserved in the output.

Comment: @Timus good point about different types, tho I guess that author asks about the implementation of the `index` i.e. `How does list.index() work under the hood?`

Comment: @0dminnimda Maybe, maybe not. :)) I suspect that this question is produced by the misunderstanding that `np.nan` and `b` simply have different values/are essentially different objects, and therefore `b` is not an element of `a`, which makes the result of `a.index(b)` obvious. But who knows ... Anyways, I didn't post it as an answer, just as a comment - and I think that's what comments are there for.

Comment: @0dminnimda: Yes, I just wanted to understand why the `float(3.1)` example works, despite being a different object after the list-array-list conversion and why the `np.nan` example works, despite not having equality to `np.nan`. You clarified this in your answer below. I did not think `list.index` would test for both `x is y` (reference) and `x == y`, but given that the code output is logical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Implementation of `list.index`

If you wanna see how `index` is implemented (in C) you can look [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8492b729ae97737d22544f2102559b2b8dd03a03/Objects/listobject.c#L2573)
To make it easier to understand I rewrote that in python:

```py
import sys


def index(self, value, start=0, stop=sys.maxsize, /):
    # make sure that start and end are in boundaries
    if start < 0:
        start += len(self)
        if start < 0:
            start = 0
    if stop < 0:
        stop += len(self)
        if stop < 0:
            stop = 0

    # iterate throughout list and try to find the value
    for i, obj in enumerate(self[start:stop]):
        if obj is value or obj == value:
            return i

    raise ValueError("%r is not in list" % value)
```

## Details of why the implementation is like that

**To understand this part I would suggest to you to read the implementation which I referenced earlier**

All magic is happening in the [`PyObject_RichCompareBool`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8492b729ae97737d22544f2102559b2b8dd03a03/Objects/object.c#L751):
if it's called like in the `index` then it behaves like `x is y or x == y`

This fact also stated in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_RichCompareBool) (`index` uses `Py_EQ`)

> int PyObject_RichCompareBool(PyObject *o1, PyObject *o2, int opid)

> Compare the values of o1 and o2 using the operation specified by opid, which must be one of Py_LT, Py_LE, Py_EQ, Py_NE, Py_GT, or Py_GE, corresponding to <, <=, ==, !=, >, or >= respectively. Returns -1 on error, 0 if the result is false, 1 otherwise. This is the equivalent of the Python expression o1 op o2, where op is the operator corresponding to opid.

> Note If o1 and o2 are the same object, PyObject_RichCompareBool() will always return 1 for Py_EQ and 0 for Py_NE.

Case with `-1` is handled by python, we don't need to worry about it. (python raises exception and automatically stops running our code)

## So how does it work?

In the end if we apply our knoledge then we can see the reason why the behaviour is like that:

```py
import numpy as np

instance1 = np.nan

l = [instance1]
instance2 = np.nanmax(l)  # RuntimeWarning: All-NaN axis encountered

print(instance1 is instance2 or instance1 == instance2)
# False therefore ValueError
```

```py
import numpy as np

instance1 = 3.1

l = [instance1]
instance2 = np.array(l).tolist()[0]

print(instance1 is instance2 or instance1 == instance2)
# True (instance1 == instance2) therefore no ValueError
```

## Additionally

Also here are your generalized examples:

```py
import numpy as np

instance1 = np.nan

l = [instance1]
instance2 = np.nanmax(l)  # RuntimeWarning: All-NaN axis encountered

assert instance1 is l[0]
assert instance1 is not instance2

assert not l.index(instance1)
assert not l.index(instance2)  # ValueError: nan is not in list
```

and

```py
import numpy as np

instance1 = 3.1

l = [instance1]
instance2 = np.array(l).tolist()[0]

assert instance1 is l[0]
assert instance1 is not instance2

assert not l.index(instance1)
assert not l.index(instance2)  # no ValueError
```

Comment: @bproxauf if this answer helped you or you like it, please do not forget to [vote up and mark the answer as a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I always do, just did not check the StackOverflow post since yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

In python you can make a `nan` valued object with:

```
In [80]: mynan=float('nan')
In [81]: id(mynan)
Out[81]: 139640449759024
```

Make another and get a different id:

```
In [82]: mynan=float('nan')
In [83]: id(mynan)
Out[83]: 139640449757264
```

`numpy` has its own version:

```
In [84]: id(np.nan)
Out[84]: 139640952170000
```

I think that always gives the same id (in a particular session)

Make a list:

```
In [85]: a = [.1, np.nan, .3, mynan]
```

`np.isnan` can test for `nan` values even where `id` and value don't work:

```
In [86]: np.isnan(a)
Out[86]: array([False,  True, False,  True])
```

As far as I know, list index first tests for `id`, then for `==`.  Remember lists store elements by `reference`.

```
In [87]: a.index(np.nan)
Out[87]: 1
In [88]: a.index(mynan)
Out[88]: 3
In [89]: a.index(float('nan'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-89-33bf9e0279e3>", line 1, in <module>
    a.index(float('nan'))
ValueError: nan is not in list
```